# Adding numbers in two different array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to add two different arrays in following manner.

A = [1 2 3 4]
B = [2 3 4 5]

A + B = [3 5 7 9]

```
<script>
function myFunction1(){

var Mmax1 = new Array();
var Mmax2 = new Array();
var L = document.getElementById("txt1").value;
var w = document.getElementById("txt2").value;
var P = document.getElementById("txt3").value;
var a = document.getElementById("txt4").value;  

    for (var x = 0; x <= L; x += 1) {
        sum[x] = x
        Mmax1[x] = w * x / 2 * (L-x) 
        Mmax2[i] = P*a*(i-a)/i;
    }
        Mmax = Mmax1 + Mmax2

</script>
```

How can this be done in Javascript?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to write something yourself? What/where exactly the problem is?

Comment: You can achieve it by using simple for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well we want to make sure the arrays aren't null and that the lengths are the same...then we can just iterate.

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4], B = [2, 3, 4, 5]
var sum = [];
    
function sumArray(a, b) {
  if (a != null && b != null && a.length == b.length) {
    for (var i = 0, len = a.length; i < a.length; i++) {
      sum.push(a[i] + b[i]);
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(sumArray(A, B));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method.

```js
var A = [1, 2, 3, 4],
  B = [2, 3, 4, 5];

var res = A
  // iterate over first array
  .map(function(v, i) {
    // sum up first array value and second
    // array value fetched by index
    return v + B[i];
  });

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var AB=[];
for(var x in A){
    AB.push(A[x]+B[x]);
}

console.log(AB);
```

Comment: looks like using the wrong language ...

Comment: Ye. Sorry. Changed it